# Show the total number of images for a specific Instagram #tag

Tags: jquery, json, instagram

**http://jsfiddle.net/MhhcS/1/**

I am trying to modify an Instagram search JS to count and display only the total number of tagged images for a certain tag.

The only response I get in my modified script is `undefined`, and I am clueless at this point.
You can see the API response from my request [**here**](https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/search?q=newyork&access_token=27703032.79547bd.418b75856eb1419f9fc1311a518db229).

What am I doing wrong or not doing at all here?

Any hint in the right direction is much appreciated...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With that structure of object you need to use the following to get `media_count`:

```
data.data[0].media_count
```

The first `data` is the variable you defined for returning information from the request. The second `data` is an array - hence the `[0]` to access the first element in it - containing the `media_count` parameter which tells you how many image were found.

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/MhhcS/2/)

Comment: It works like an absolute charm, thanks for a quick and satisfying answer!

Comment: @Trollsyn no problem. Could you please click the green tick on the left to accept this answer -- assuming it helped, of course :)

Comment: I was searching for where to mark the question as answered... Thanks again! :)

Comment: rory how about getting total number of images in any profile ?(https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/".$user_id."/media/recent/?access_token=xxxx )